# Difference in Generic Signature in Java

Tags: java, generics

We have made in a tutorial an example with the following signture (as part of an interface)

```
<T> List<Comparable<T>> sort(Collection<Comparable<T>> c, boolean ascending);
```

We have found it nearly impossible to implement that method without warnings:

```
public <T> List<Comparable<T>> sort(Collection<Comparable<T>> c, boolean ascending) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
}
```

The error in the line `Collections.sort(list)` we get is:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not 
applicable for the arguments (List<T>). The inferred type T is not a valid 
substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

However, it works for the following signature:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> sort(Collection<T> c, boolean ascending);
```

With that signature, the code above (implementation of `sort`) just works as expected. I would like to know what is the reason for that.

Comment: And the question is? I guess why the second works and the first not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.sort` expects a `List<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, i.e. the compiler needs to be able to tell that the element type `T` of the list it is sorting extends `Comparable<E>` where `E` is `T`, a superclass of `T` or an interface implemented by `T`.  Your first signature with `public <T> List<Comparable<T>> sort` doesn't enforce this, so you can't `Collections.sort` a `List<T>`.  You could make it work by saying

```
List<Comparable<T>> list = new ArrayList<Comparable<T>>();
```

to match the type that your sort method returns, but the problem with this is that it's rather inflexible - it can only sort a `Collection<Comparable<Foo>>`, *not* a `Collection<Bar>` where `Bar implements Comparable<Foo>`.  The most flexible approach would be to stick with the `new ArrayList<T>()` but use a signature like

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> sort(Collection<T> c, boolean ascending);
```

which places the minimum restriction on `T` to make the sort valid - it would work with `Bar extends Foo implements Comparable<Foo>`, which your second signature doesn't allow (that would require `Bar implements Comparable<Bar>`).

Comment: Thank's a lot for the very detailed answer, and the idea to make it even more flexible. I will add that to our tutorial example.

Answer (score 3):

A list of `Comparable<T>`s is a list of objects which are comparable with `T`s. One could not say if these objects themselves are `T`s. Thus it's impossible to compare two elements with each other.

`T`s, which happen to be comparable with other `T`s, can be compared with each other. And so sorting a list of such `T`s is possible.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the simple but deep explanation. If I could only accept 2 answers ... :-(